# How to give variable in css by using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Usually using jquery we ll give css as like this

```
$("p").css("margin", "20px");
```

In my project i have code like this

```
var descMargin = productImage + productName + 26;
$(".product-compare-modal__grid--label").css("margin-top",descMargin);});
```

store it in a variable and giving.

here we are not mentioning any "px" or "%"

Is this the correct method of using? or I need to change?

Comment: You should concat `px` to the variable

Comment: I believe jQuery infers pixels where no unit is specified.

Comment: That would work absolutely fine.

Comment: @Utkanos: Only if it's a number, not if it's a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - interesting. What does it infer from a string, e.g. `"46"`, then?

Comment: @Utkanos: As far as I can tell, nothing. It just passes it along, and the style object ignores it. Makes sense: It's easy and quick to test if a property or argument's value is a number, but checking whether it's an all-digits string is much more overhead. So they just do the number check and assume you know what you're doing if you pass a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this the correct method of using?

It's fine **if** your `descMargin` is meant to be in pixels (not `%` or `em` or `rem` or ...), and **if** it's actually a number (I'm guessing from your code snippet that it is).

If you just use a number, jQuery converts it to a string and appends `px` for you. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2):

> When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add `px` to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method.

What you don't want to do is pass it a string that's all digits. So don't give it `"26"`, for instance; but `26` is fine.

So:

```
// This:
$("p").css("margin", 20);
// Does the same thing as this:
$("p").css("margin", "20px");
// But DON'T do this:
$("p").css("margin", "20"); // <== Wrong
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var div = $("div");
test("50px");
setTimeout(test.bind(null, 40), 300);
setTimeout(test.bind(null, "30"), 600);

function test(value) {
  var rawValue = String(value).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var rawPadding;
  var result;
  
  div.css("padding-left", value);
  var result = div.css("padding-left").replace(/\D/g, '') == rawValue ? "worked" : "failed";
  $("<p>")
    .html("Result for " + JSON.stringify(value) + ": " + result)
    .appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> As i know that the by default when you pass value using the **.css()**
>   that value will be taken as the **"px"** you want change the measure
>   unit to the css  property you need to give it manually.

this the way how you can give it manually

```js
var descMargin = productImage + productName + 26;


$(".product-compare-modal__grid--label").css("margin-top",descMargin + "px");

$(".product-compare-modal__grid--label").css("margin-top",descMargin + "%");

$(".product-compare-modal__grid--label").css("margin-top",descMargin + "em" );

$(".product-compare-modal__grid--label").css("margin-top",descMargin + "pt" );
```

and here is the unit list you can apply

[CSS units's list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)